# Decipher AES128b based on a known set of raw data and encrypted block

Tags: encryption, aes

I'm planning to use AES 128b ECB to encrypt a data block that will be transmitted over an insecurity medium.

How safe would it be if the attacker gets one (1) set of raw_data<=>encrypted_block? Is it possible to decipher the private key based only on one (1) known value?

> For example:
>
> raw_data: (data1) and encrypted_block: (encrypted1)
> The attacker knows that (encrypted1) is the encryption of (data1).

Comment: Modern encryption algorithms are designed to be immune to known plaintext attacks...

Comment: Do not use ECB mode in new work and update legacy work ASAP, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret. Or use GCM mode if available.